# protractor click on element on custom dropdown list

Tags: angularjs, protractor, browser-automation

I'm using protractor to test my website and have custom dropdown that open after i click on a button

var list = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="project"]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/button'));

list.click();

and after that i want to click on the 3 item and when I took the xpath of the element I want

```
var itemtoselect = element(by.xpath('/html/body/ul[2]/li[3]/a'));
```

and execute the click operation but nothing has happen.
how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The question lacks a little bit of detail, and unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment and ask for it.*

But Ill try to explain some other ways of accessing that element

**Firstly,** this issue happened to me on a previous project when opening up a previewed document, and what was happening at least in my case was that there were multiple `/html/body`s so I could not reference the second one via a typical xpath.

As a result, I had to locate the element in another fashion.

`element.all(by.repeater('SOME LIST NAME')).get(2).click();`

**The goal:** You should find some common aspect that is shared between all the list items whether it be a class, id, partial text, and use that in conjunction with `element.all(by.SOMETHING(SOMETHING).get(2).click();`

http://timothymartin.azurewebsites.net/protractor-cheat-sheet/

The link above has several examples of alternate ways to find the list item, good luck!